# Pdflatex cannot see .cls files

Tags: texlive, texlive-2020

So I have installed TeXlive 2020, but whenever I run pdflatex on any main.tex I get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `article.cls' not found.
```

I have checked and article.cls is where it should be at

```
/home/me/utils/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
```

When I run `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFDIST` I get

```
/home/me/utils/texlive/texmf-dist
```

And my $PATH contains

```
/home/me/utils/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux
```

Is there some extra path in TeXLive I have not set? I think this is the same problem as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309651/latex-cant-find-cls-files), but this was never answered so I thought I would make a new question.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: When the error occurs I can give latex the path to article.cls and it works, but this leads me down rabbit holes of needing to manually specify every .cls and .sty file everytime I compile, which is not feasible

Comment: When you say you run pdflatex, exactly how? Comand line? Or via editor?

Comment: Via the command line! So just `pdflatex main.tex`. I get the same bug with `latex main.text`

Comment: I assume you tried the command `kpsewhich article.cls' no response?

Comment: Yep, nothing :(

Comment: Have you tried `mktexlsr /home/me/utils/texlive/texmf-dist' ?

Comment: I get `mktexlsr: /home/me/utils/texlive/texmf-dist: directory not writable. Skipping...`

Comment: Oh after searching about mktexlsr for a bit I found that TEXMFHOME is set to a directory that doesn't exist (/home/me/texmf). But setting this explicitly to `/home/me/utils/texlive/texmf-dist` doesn't change anything

Comment: texmf-dist is not your TEXMFHOME, but if texmf-dist is not writable, then ls-R can not be added to it and then files are not found.

Comment: That was just a guess from me. Any idea how to make texmf-dist writeable? I don't really know what that means...

Comment: you are probably not the owner of texmf-dist. The return of `ls -ld /home/me/utils/texlive/texmf-dist' will inform you. Did you run your installation of TeXLive under your account or under the root account?

Comment: Ah I think I did it under sudo... Do I need to uninstall and reinstall again? I ran ``sudo mktexls /home/daniel/utils/texlive/texmf-dist`` and it ran, but neither ``pdflatex main.tex`` or ``sudo pdflatex main.tex`` work, the latter doesn't even recognise the pdflatex command. Sorry if this me being an idiot, I am a bit of a linux noob!

Comment: the shell command chown  let you change the files owner.

Comment: Then you will have to update the complete tree structure by mktexlsr

Comment: Reinstalling not in sudo fixed it all, it was the ownership. Many thanks! @gigiair if you want to write that as the answer I will accept it, or I will put an answer down for any that is search with the same issue.